# Android timer updating a textview (UI)

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm using a timer to create a stop watch. The timer works by increasing a integer value. I want to then display this value in the activity by constantly updating a textview.

Here's my code from the service where I try and update the activity's textview:

```
protected static void startTimer() {
    isTimerRunning = true; 
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            elapsedTime += 1; //increase every sec
            StopWatch.time.setText(formatIntoHHMMSS(elapsedTime)); //this is the textview
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}
```

I got some kind of error about updating the UI in the wrong thread.

How can I adapt my code to accomplish this task of constantly updating the textview?

Comment: im not familiar with the andriod api but you might have to manually call repaint() or whatever method u use when you update the textfield constanlty.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
protected static void startTimer() {
    isTimerRunning = true; 
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            elapsedTime += 1; //increase every sec
            mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}

public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        StopWatch.time.setText(formatIntoHHMMSS(elapsedTime)); //this is the textview
    }
};
```

Above code will work...

Note: Handlers must be created in your main thread so that you can modify UI content.

Comment: Nice simple solution.  One correction to make though -- the final brace "}" completing your handler definition requires a ";"

Comment: @Nirav you might want to note for people that the package for Handler is android.os and not one of the others.

Comment: The semi colon is supposed to be after the hander assignment, not the where it now is.

Comment: Note that "schedule" is useful alternative to "scheduleAtFixedRate", for cases where instead of exact time, you want some task to be repeated after a given delay. The difference is that if one run is delayed (beyond its requested time) by say 1/2 sec due to other activity, the next run will be the specified time after that DELAYED start. I use this when there is something I want to check occasionally, but if there ever happens to be a delay, there is no point in checking again quickly.

Comment: i think any code on handler need to implement the onresume and onstop methods to safely start and stop handler/timer

Answer (score 8):

You should use `Handler` instead to update UI every X seconds. Here is another question that show an example: [Repeat a task with a time delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay/6242292#6242292)

Your approach doesn't work because you are trying to update UI from non-UI thread. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 6):

```
StopWatch.time.post(new Runnable() {
    StopWatch.time.setText(formatIntoHHMMSS(elapsedTime));
});
```

this code block is based on Handler but you don't need to create your own Handler instance.

Comment: Note to future readers: There is no built-in class "StopWatch" in Android; this answer is referring to OP's code example, in which "StopWatch" is the name of the OP's TextView.

Answer (score 2):

TimerTask implements Runnable, which would make it a thread. You can not update the main UI thread directly from a different thread without some work. 
One thing you could do is use Async Task to create the timer and publish an update every second that will update the UI.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `StopWatch.time` is some static or public reference to your TextView.  Instead of doing this, you should implement a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to communicate between your timer (which runs from a separate thread) and your TextView.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following utility :

```
/**
 * Created by Ofek on 19/08/2015.
 */
public class TaskScheduler extends Handler {
    private ArrayMap<Runnable,Runnable> tasks = new ArrayMap<>();
    public void scheduleAtFixedRate(final Runnable task,long delay,final long period) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                task.run();
                postDelayed(this, period);
            }
        };
        tasks.put(task, runnable);
        postDelayed(runnable, delay);
    }
    public void scheduleAtFixedRate(final Runnable task,final long period) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                task.run();
                postDelayed(this, period);
            }
        };
        tasks.put(task, runnable);
        runnable.run();
    }
    public void stop(Runnable task) {
        Runnable removed = tasks.remove(task);
        if (removed!=null) removeCallbacks(removed);
    }

}
```

Then anywhere in code that runs by the UI Thread you can use it simply like this:

```
TaskScheduler timer = new TaskScheduler();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                time.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(GamePlay.instance().getLevelTime()));
            }
        },1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use **[Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)**.

this code **increase a counter every one second** and **show and update** counter value on a **textView**.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        startTimer();
    }


    int i = 0;
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            i++;
            textView.setText("counter:" + i);
            startTimer();
        }
    };

    public void startTimer() {
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }

    public void cancelTimer() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: plus 1 for the onstop

Answer (score -1):

I use this way:

```
String[] array = {"man", "for", "think"}; 
int j;
```

Then add more `onCreate`:

```
TextView t = findViewById(R.id.textView);

new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        t.setText("I " + array[j] + " You");
        j++;
        if (j == array.length - 1) j = 0;
        start();
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score -3):

```
 timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //your actions

            }
        },1*1000);//1 sec
```