# Change text color in button every interval of time

Tags: android

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("first iteration","first iteration");
    btn1.setTextColor(Color.rgb((int)(Math.random()*255), (int)(Math.random()*255), (int)(Math.random()*255))); 
    Log.i("iterating","iteratinggggggggg"); 
                        }
                    }, 0, 1000);
```

in Logcat:

```
01-07 02:39:09.789: I/first iteration(16568): first iteration
01-07 02:39:09.789: I/iterating(16568): iteratinggggggggg
01-07 02:39:10.781: I/first iteration(16568): first iteration
```

which means that `btn1.setTextColor(...)` is executing **only once**!
I would like the **Button Text** to be changed every **1 second**.

Any expert can help?

Thank to Ole I could find out a solution for my problem that I would like to share with you:

**SOLUTION:**

```
// UPDATING BTN TEXT DYNAMICALLY
    Runnable myRunnableUpdater = new Runnable()
    { 
        public void run() {
            colorGenerator();
            hd.postDelayed(myRunnableUpdater, 1000);
        }
    };
    void startRepeatingTask()
    {
        myRunnableUpdater.run(); 
    }
    void stopRepeatingTask()
    {
        hd.removeCallbacks(myRunnableUpdater);
    }

    private void colorGenerator() {
        btn1.setTextColor(Color.rgb((int)(Math.random()*255), (int)(Math.random()*255), (int)(Math.random()*255)));
    }
    //END OF UPDATING BTN TEXT DYNAMICALLY!!
```

1)Do not forget to declare `Handler hd`
2)Also, `hd = new Handler()` in `onCreate()`
3) Use `startRepeatingTask()` wherever you desire your repetitive code to be repeated.
4) Use `stopRepeatingTask()` wherever you desire to stop repeating.

Cheers! ;)

Comment: Are you sure? You have 2 "first iteration" Log outputs 1 sec apart and it will always output "first iteration" when the TimerTask repeats as it's a String.

Comment: yes i'm sure, i tested it many times! maybe because rgb is a static method and cannot be changed every instance?

Comment: And you are not getting any errors in LogCat? You are updating the UI from outside the main thread. I would expect your application to force close.

Comment: yes it is force closing true i forgot to mention that..

Comment: That would be why everything isn't being updated :)

Comment: No it's not repeating, the color changes only once, then the application closes!

Comment: I don't understand guys where's the problem? :P

Comment: You cannot change/update your view (button) outside of the UI thread.

Comment: @wtsang02 thank you for clarifying, you mean i should use the  runOnUiThread thingy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is force-closing because you are trying to update UI elements from a thread created by the `Timer`. Only the main thread is allowed to update the UI. This can be solved using a `Handler`

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6702767/742660) answer on how to implement this.