# PostDelayed or Thread with thread.sleep()

Tags: android

If I need to update UI components ( like textview) every second as long as the activity is visible.  Would you recommend creating a thread (with thread.sleep) which does postOnUi call OR do I use handler with postDelayed?

I am not sure which would be more efficient provided that I have multiple textviews

Thanks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mixing up some concepts. `Handler`'s `postDelayed()` indeed will run a `Runnable` after some time lapse, but only once.

For what you want to do you've several choices:

- Sleeping the `Thread` is one of them. A disatvantage of this is that the `Thread` might cause an exception and this way your execution could become unstable. Also, you'll have just one `Thread` and you won't free it up even if it's sleeping, so you're using resources that you might not need at a time.
- Another approach is using an `AsyncTask`. This is recommended, however, for short tasks. If you plan running this task for a longer period of time, `AsyncTask` is probably not a good choice.
- You can run a background `Service` with a `Handler` to update the UI. Depends on what you're trying to achieve.
- You'll probably want to have a look at `ScheduledExecutorService`. It has a method called `scheduleAtFixedRate()` which will do exactly that, execute a `Runnable` each X time specified by one of the parameters. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I should've clarified. By postDelayed, I meant calling itself every x amount of second. One thing I didn't understand, what do you mean by "having a thread won't free up resources". When you call thread.sleep, it gives the UI thread and other threads chance to do their work. I like your last option, except it seems that it does not execute on UI thread so I have to also post it to UI thread

Comment: The control is indeed given to the UI thread, but you still have that `Thread` loaded into memory, so it's not freed up but waiting until next execution. This shouldn't be an issue, however, but you asked about efficiency so I just noted that. For the UI issue, have a look at this, it might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700802/android-timer-updating-a-textview-ui