# Progressively increase integer / increase int on regular interval

Tags: java, android

I just recently started playing around with Java/Android.

I am trying to make a very simple Android app. I want a number to be progressively increased. Something like:

```
int x = 0;
```

then every 0.1 seconds, x++. Then I can set the text of a textview

```
.setText(String.valueOf(x));
```

So in the program it will have an integer number increasing from 0 by 1 every 0.1 seconds.

Meanwhile all other functions/code should run normally while this is happening in the background

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll look into it and try it out now!

Comment: you can take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700802/android-timer-updating-a-textview-ui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use the TextView's internal handler and its postDelayed method, to increment the int . E.g.

```
textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(++x));    
            textView.postDelayed(this, 100);
       }
  }, 100);
```

where 100 is 100 milliseconds. Don't forget to call

```
textView.removeCallbacks(null);
```

when your activity is paused

Comment: what does this mean? http://i.imgur.com/iECgcpM.png , a better question is, what to i replace textView with?

Comment: `postDelayed` returns boolean. remove `(TextView)` from the second line. For postDelayed you don't need the cast, since the method is part of the super class.

Comment: NVM I FIXED IT. Thanks. trying it now. /*the .setText is red now, "cannot resolve method setText (java.lang.string)"*/

Comment: you need couple of brackets more. it should be `((TextView) findViewById(R.id...)).setText(...)`

Comment: you have to call `textView.removeCallbacks(null);`

Comment: on the top of the run method, add: `if (pressed == 0) return;` and run it again

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
int x = 0;

TimerTask scanTask;
Timer t = new Timer();

public void incrementValue(){

scanTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
               x++;
        }};

    t.schedule(scanTask, 100, 100); 
 }
```

and use  t.cancel();  whenever you want to stop the task.