# Change Button text with a timer

Tags: android, timer

I want to show a text on button for 3 seconds and after that change the button text with another word. how i can do this?
i used these codes but just seen the second text.

```
public void TimePause ()
{
    int Time_1 = (Calendar.getInstance()).get(Calendar.SECOND)+3;
    while ( ((Calendar.getInstance()).get(Calendar.SECOND)) != Time_1 )
    {

    }
}


if (tasbihat==0)
{
     //text one
     counter.setText("word one");
     checkPoint = 1;
     EndViber.vibrate(500);
     // pause 
     TimePause();
     tasbihat = 33;
     //text two
     counter.setText("33");
     swZekrtxt.setText("word two");
}
```

Comment: Its because of tasbihat value . if (tasbihat==0) you are comparing here = 0 and  in if tasbihat = 33;

Comment: Look at this. Use Handler for delaying anything http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700802/android-timer-updating-a-textview-ui/6702767#6702767

Comment: @Pravin thank you for answer , but these are some part of my code .

Comment: just set tasbihat = 0; when your task is done so next time it will go in your if condition

Comment: format your code properly and use english only.

Comment: @progressive_overload as you see i wrote  english  ! and as you know it,s not important what is between   quotations  !

Comment: @dariush sometimes it improves code readability if any output is in english. format your code anyways pls... it is a mess.

Comment: @dariush thank you for you edit! :) but i still don't know what "swZekrtxt" and "tashibat" means! ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `Handler`. Don't forget initialize **mButton** before using.

```
private Button mButton;
private void changeTextButton() {
    int delayTime = 3000; // 3 sec
    mButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mButton.setText("Some text");
        }
    }, delayTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    Timer t=new Timer();
    TimerTask task=new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          button.setText("");//Example
        }
    };
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,0,3000);//3 seconds
```