# Unable to communicate between two WebViews

Tags: android, android-webview

To explain what I want to achieve I wrote what I'm able to do and then - when a problem appears. What works well:

1) I have `webView1` containing in loaded HTML

```
<button onclick="android.buttonPressed();">Click</button>
```

binded with interface:

```
private class WebAppInterface1 {
    Context context;

    WebAppInterface1(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void buttonPressed() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "buttonPressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The HTML button works.

2) I have `webView2` containing in loaded HTML

```
<script>
    function f() {
        document.write("bla bla bla");
    }
</script>
```

Then I call

```
webView2.loadUrl("javascript:f();");
```

in android code and it works too.

---

Now I want to modify `webView2`'s page by pressing button in `webView1`. Technically it means that I want to call `f()` inside `webView2` when JS interface detected click in `webView1`. So I add this line

```
webView2.loadUrl("javascript:f();");
```

in `buttonPressed()` function inside JS interface. But it has no effect. What can cause the problem? Are there any limitations in connecting these reciever and sender? Maybe I missed some settings or permissions?

There are my project files, I tried to make them as simple as possible: [layout](https://pastebin.com/98iZZF0F), [html](https://pastebin.com/jWgn7Vva), [java](https://pastebin.com/iGuwb4FQ). Didn't edit other files. Can give any additional information if needed.

Comment: remove semicolon webView2.loadUrl("javascript:f()");

Comment: @AndyDeveloper unfortunately that doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that my problem is related to another problem: *one can't update UI from non-main thread* (was covered on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700802/android-timer-updating-a-textview-ui) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)). But in my case there isn't any errors for some reason. Maybe because of JavaScript isn't as "strict" as Java.

So solved by adding `android.os.Handler` in my activity class, assigning it in `onCreate` function:

```
handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        webView2.loadUrl("javascript:f()");
    }
}
```

and accessing it in `buttonPressed` function:

```
handler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
```

P.S. Another way is to wrap calling `webView2.loadUrl("javascript:f()");` by `Runnable` and calling `runOnUiThread(runnable)`. It looks more neat:

```
webView1.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void buttonPressed() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView2.loadUrl("javascript:f()");
            }
        });
    }
}, "android");
```

P.P.S. [Enabling Java 8](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html) in `app/build.gradle` allows to write it even more neat:

```
runOnUiThread(()->{webView2.loadUrl("javascript:f()");});
```