# Android Development: How to set a timer to multiple checkboxes when they're unchecked?

Tags: android

How do I set a timer on all of the checkboxes at the same time if I were to uncheck them all at once? If I uncheck "checkbox1" and set up a timer for that checkbox, wouldn't unchecking "checkbox2" override that timer?

- I have 3 checkboxes and 1 textview,
- All checkboxes in the state of checked.
- I want to create a timer when any of them is unchecked.
- I wish to have a independent timer for each checkbox

For example, when "checkbox1" is unchecked, I wish to create a timer that lasts for 5 minutes and when it only has 1 minute left, I want it to change the textview's text to "you have 1 minute left" as a reminder that the timer is ending soon.

```
public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!buttonView.isChecked()) {
        new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (millisUntilFinished < 60000) {
                    map.get(buttonView).setText("1 min left!");
                } else if (millisUntilFinished < 30000) {
                    map.get(buttonView).setText("30 sec left!");
                } else {
                    map.get(buttonView).setText(millisUntilFinished/60000 + ":" + (millisUntilFinished%60000)/1000);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                map.get(buttonView).setText("Spawned!");
            }

        }.start();
    } else if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
        // cancel the timer basically
    }
}
```

Unlike what i originally wanted to do, i've created a textview for each checkbox, so it wouldn't be confusing to the user. I've created a map which contains (Checkbox, TextView). How do i cancel the timer when the checkbox is unchecked? do i make an arraylist? if so, where would i add the timer into the arraylist?

Comment: I think using the same textview to display state of timers for three individual checkboxes will be very confusing for the user.  I suggest you review your functional requirements.  Either have 1 checkbox or have 3 textviews.  If, however, you do want to override the previous timer when you uncheck the second checkbox, then your existing solution should be fine.

Comment: You have multiple checkboxes but one textbox.  How to you wish to handle: *textview's text to "you have 1 minute left"* for each change in checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My main concern is...how do i set a timer on all of them at the same time if i were to uncheck them all at once?

You can use [CountdownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). Set an `onCheckedChangeListener` on your `CheckBoxes`and create a new instance of your `CountdownTimer` each time.

> if i uncheck "checkbox1" and set up a timer for that checkbox, wouldn't unchecking "checkbox2" override that timer?

Not if you create separate instances of the `CountdownTimer` for each one it shouldn't give you a problem.

You could store these instances of `CountdownTimer` in an `Array` if you needed to so you could iterate over them and cancel and restart each one if you needed.

Comment: I followed this set up and finally got what i expected my app to perform. thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

There are all manner of timers and such available to Java / Android. Just looking at the 'related' topics here turns up:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android?rq=1)
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how?lq=1)
[and so on...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639432/repeating-a-method-every-60-seconds-in-java-on-android?lq=1)

If you want to have multiple timers for your UI you could create a class with the timer and kick off multiple instances - one for each check box event. Keep an array of these objects in your UI class.

You could also have a single timer for the first event and store the deltas for any subsequent check box events.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Create three timers and simply start them with 5 minutes each when a checkbox is false or unchecked or whatever the property is. Use the schedule method of each timer to do that 1 minute left thing you're talking about.