# does doInBackground of asynTask run in background?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, countdowntimer

I am trying to create a countdowntimer which will run even though the app is sent to the background? I am not sure how to implement this using services, so would it be possible to run it in the doBackground method of a asyncTask, and will the timer continue to run even when the app is "minimized"?

thanx

Comment: No. AsyncTask is still bound to the context so if your context gets killed, it will cancel. You need to use a service.

Comment: No u have to make service

Comment: thax for reply, how can I create a service with a countdown timer? I simply want the service to run the entire time, and countdown, however how do I notify the service once the countdown has expired and the call the onDestroy() method?

Comment: @user2042227 I believe the question is correctly answered and you shouldn't use comments to ask a second question. To be honest that 2nd question is not even valid for StackOverflow criteria. I suggest you first have a good read and a good try to implement the Service yourself.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8123675/2591002)

Answer (score 5):

`doInBackgroud()` runs on a different thread. But it does not means it isnt bound with the app. If the app stops, `AsyncTask` stop with it. So your timer would be of no help here.

What you can do is, use `AlarmManager` to call a `BroadcastReceiver` denoting that the timer's up. This `BroadcastReceiver` can in turn call up a `Service` or `Activity` in which you can do whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to using asynctask to run countdown timer and if you want to show on UI, you can not use doInBackground, because it can not meddle to UI.

I think you should use thread for this issue. if you want/dont want timer continue to run when the app is minimize, you can use a boolean variable to control (**must use runOnUiThread to meddle to UI**)

How to use:

```
    boolean stop=false;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!stop) {
                //YOUR CODE HERE
            }
        }
    });
```

If you want to stop timer when app minimize, use can set `stop=true` in `onPause()` of activity

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    stop=true;
}
```

and if you want timer re-play when activity resume, you can set `stop=false` in `onResume()`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    stop=false;
}
```