# How to show other layout when count down finish?

Tags: android

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

    public void onFinish() {
        setContentView(R.layout.another);
    }
}.start();
```

But when the user closes the app, it does not work.

How to do ?

Comment: Is onFinish() invoked?

Comment: I'd swap Fragments, instead. Because dealing with different Views (thrown in by different layouts) in the same Activity or Fragment can be tricky.

Comment: Try search AlarmManager.

Comment: swaping fragments should be the cleanest solution, but just calling setContentView will work, your problem is with that CountDownTimer heres the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123231/android-count-down-timer-in-background