# How to properly implement timers in Android?

Tags: java, android, timer

I am trying to make a simple app that tracks work time.
MainActivity features a TextView representing a timer and four buttons, for starting, pausing, resuming and stopping.

So far I have two classes for modelling the timer, TimerCountdown and TimerCountup (for overtime) that initiate timers using `android.os.CountDownTimer;`, update the TextView and trigger a system notification to notify the user once they have finished. TimerCountdown updates tView every second and after 8 hours it will send a notification to the user and initiate TimerCountup to track overtime for another 2 hours.

What is the correct way to ensure those timers keep running if the application is in the background? Do I have to wrap the two Timer classes into a Service? If so, how would I do this, since they are holding references to the context, which is apparently not allowed?  Unfortunately the documentation for `android.os.CountDownTimer;` does not mention how it behaves when the applications enters the background. In order to restore progress once the application is destroyed I will probably use a serialized object eventually, I am just not sure how to properly handle background activity.

Also, what would be the best way to ensure the notification (such as a vibration) gets triggered after the timer reaches 0? The app will probably be either in background by then, or destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want a timer which will work at the background,to do this you should extend service class.There is an answered  question which is similar to yours.You can check it out [Android count down timer in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123231/android-count-down-timer-in-background)

Comment: Thanks, refactoring the two Timer classes into one, extending it into a service and calling startForeground(); did what I was looking for