# How to run a method at the time set by user?

Tags: android, timer

I am making an application in which I have to execute the method at the time set by user.
Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Does the method need to run if the app is exited before that time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to implement this would be to create a `Service` in your application that invokes an `AlarmManager`. The `AlarmManager` is used to trigger an event set in the future and invoking it in a `service` enables you to run it even when your application is closed.
A very fine tutorial of the same can be found [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html). Although i would suggest you to go through the `AlarmManager` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) first.

Answer (score 1):

Define a `PendingIntent` that will execute the operation then setup `Alarm` to execute the `PendingIntent`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

And others related:

[Android timer? How-to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how)

[How to set a timer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android)