# background task to automatic calling webservice after some time duration in Android

Tags: android, timer, background-process

Here i develop one android application, I want to call web service automatically in background after some time duration which i set, How to do this i don't know.

please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use timer. Here is useful link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to call your app at your set interval. Whenever your app is called by it, access your webservice.