# How to stop service at particular time on Android?

Tags: android, android-service

Start my service at : 8am. I don't know how to stop service at specific time.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this,
(int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, pi);
```

I want Myservice start at 8am and stop at 6pm in everyday.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: In the same way to trigger the alarm at 8 am to start your service, do the same but to stop the service at 6 pm.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android.. go through this link

Answer (score 0):

you could use the AlarmManager, .cancel(PendingIntent intent) at the myService.class, checking whether it's 6pm and cancel the alarm if the intent exists.

Check the API:
[Alarm Manager API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old question but I came across this issue myself today and figured a way to do it:
You can use a new service which stops your service, and start that service in the desired time on a daily basis using alarm manager, like this:

Define the service which will stop your service:

```
package com.youractivity;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;


public class MyServiceTerminator extends Service {

  @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
  }


public void onCreate()
  {
     Intent service = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    stopService(service);   //stop MyService
    stopSelf();     //stop MyServiceTerminator so that it doesn't keep running uselessly
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
  //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
    return null;
  }
}
```

add the following code after the one you posted, and run the method inside your activity:

```
private void stopRecurringAlarm(Context context) {
    Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3"));
    updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyServiceTerminator.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, intent,    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pintent);
}
```

this way the service will be scheduled to start as you posted above, and scheduled to stop at 6 as shown in the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlarmManager for scheduling and cancel method to stop.

```
alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
```

you can find all your necessary information here
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html