# Android Fatal Timer-0 RunTimeException

Tags: android, timer

In Android, i am using Timer class to check wifi connection in mobile every second, because i want to Turn On GPS, when device is not using wifi. But it is showing me fatal Timer-0 RunTimeException.

Here is my timer function

```
public void checkWifi()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                             .isConnectedOrConnecting();
            if (!isWifi) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(hourlyTask, 0l, 1000);
}
```

Here is my LogCat

```
  02-14 02:52:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1539): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
  02-14 02:52:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1539): Process: com.example.gpsco11wifialert, PID: 1539
  02-14 02:52:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1539): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
  02-14 02:52:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1539):   at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
  02-14 02:52:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1539):   at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
  02-14 02:52:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1539):   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:221)
  02-14 02:52:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1539):   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:221)
  02-14 02:52:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1539):   at android.location.LocationManager.wrapListener(LocationManager.java:844)
  02-14 02:52:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1539):   at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:857)
  02-14 02:52:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1539):   at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:454)
  02-14 02:52:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1539):   at com.example.gpsco11wifialert.GpsC011Wifi$MyLocationListener$4.run(GpsC011Wifi.java:213)
  02-14 02:52:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1539):   at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: so try to add Looper.prepare() inside your Runnnable

Comment: ya i tried it, but still same error..

Answer (score 1):

As the error says in logcat you're calling it from a worker thread, Use `Handler's` or `AsyncTask` to do it.

But by looking at your requirement i suggest you to go with `BradcastReceiver` that listens for wifi state.

For Broadcastreceiver: [BroadcastReceiver when wifi or 3g network state changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733121/broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or-3g-network-state-changed)

For handler:[Android + FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0 (Removing ImageView using timer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090359/android-fatal-exception-timer-0-removing-imageview-using-timer)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not feasible at all but still you can try this to avoid this error. Or if you don't want to use this then you can try Asynctask class that will solve your problem.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

This will remove your error.

Comment: Well in my case it is perfectly working fine. where exactly you have defined this code.

Comment: I am calling this method from inside onLocationChanged(location) of location listener.

Comment: Can you put this inside run method before calling anything put this and try.