# edittext clear text after n seconds

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-handler

I want to empty an `EditText` based on a timer, according to the following behaviour:

> At time `t1`, the user starts typing. The `EditText` should be cleared
>   at time `t1` + 10 seconds.
>
> Once the `EditText` has been cleared, the timer should stop.
>
> When the user types in it again, at time `t2`, the field should be cleared at `t2` + 10 seconds, and so forth.

I tried using a `Handler` in the `afterTextChanged` method in the `TextChangedListener`.

However, this is not giving the desired behaviour: the `Handler` is started when the user starts to type but from then on, it keeps clearing the text *every* 10 seconds, even when the user hasn't typed anything (which seems obvious from the way I have coded).

But I do not know how I can change it so that the text gets clears after 10 seconds from when the user starts typing something, rather than every 10 seconds non-stop.

Isn't there a way to use a `Timer`, that's better than using `Handlers`? `Handlers` seem like a thread running in parallel once triggered.

Comment: you need to cancel the run and restart again `m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask)`. call `removeCallbacks`this will stop the run.

Comment: Is this a "costly" operation in terms of CPU? Can I prefer this over a timer?

Comment: even if you use a timer you need to cancel and restart the timer task.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Timer...

[How to set a timer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android) 
and
http://writecodeeasy.blogspot.com/2012/08/androidtutorial-timer-p1.html

you can setup the timer to run only once after specific seconds too.! Try it Hope it helps!

Comment: I think my problem is, even if I create a timer, I need to cancel it and restart it. I need to clear text after 10 seconds from when the user starts typing and somehow when I called the timer withing the onTextChanged, and cancel it in afterTextChanged, nothing happenS!

Comment: Timer is the best thing that can achieve your requirement.. make sure ur putting the right values for the date. u can set up Toast or Log methods to check if the time really started and executed the method you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID);
text.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
Runnable myRun = new Runnable(){
 public void run() 
        {
            text.setText("");
        }   
};
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         myHandler.postDelayed(myRun,10000);
  }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, intcount, int after) {
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
          int count) {
   myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRun);

  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried after Raghunandan's post. However Nothing happens. As in the text field is not cleared

Comment: myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRun); is in onTextChanged

Comment: If the handler callback is called during onTextChanged, how will the handler be  even allowed to run during afterTextChanged??

Comment: While enter a text in edit text the onText will called so I removed the handler, after calling the onText it must call afterText there I will start the handler from this it will start the timer as 10s

Comment: Thanks No_Rulz. I got the idea. However, the time just elapses after the text appears. Infact the EditText box that I have used is simply for "displaying". It is not of input type. So I dont know how relevant it is. What about TextView. can I do something like this?

Comment: Then how did you put the text in Edit

Comment: I mean I used the text as EditText and set it with text.setText(".."). However the point is this text is visbile when the user clicks a button. The only thing I want to take care is that it goes away in 10 seconds from the time it is shown.

Comment: Ohh after clicking the button you want to start a timer. not at editing your edit text am i correct? If it correct means in btnClickListener you will call your handler