# Send request from client side in intervals

Tags: java, client-server

I want to send request from Client(Socket) to server with the interval of some time like maybe 5 minutes. Is there any workaround to achieve that. 
And the same thing is possible in Android or not ?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Do you have a specific, answerable question?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or a Thread

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                doStuff();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve it using [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [java.util.TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

Please have a look at below posts for samples:

- [Android timer? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how)
- [How to set a timer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android)
- [developer android Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)