# How to set a timer to run another activity in a function? Android app

Tags: java, android, timer

I want the toast message to display(if clicked on the right answer), but not go to the next activity directly. So i want to set a timer for like 2 seconds so the user can easily read it, and then go to the next activity. What is wrong with this code?

```
public void rightAnsnextQ (View view)  
{  
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdQuestion.class);


    Toast.makeText(this, "Good job", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling sleep on the ui thread which is wrong. It blocks the ui thread. You should never block the ui thread.

```
 Thread.sleep(2000); // remove this
```

Instead use `Handler` postDelayed with a delay of 2 seconds

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
 public void run() {
     // do something
     Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, ThirdQuestion.class);
     // If you just use this that is not a valid context. Use ActivityName.this
     startActivity(intent);
   }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

try below code:-

```
private final int interval = 1000; // 1 Second
private Handler handler = new Handler();
Private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "C'Mom no hands!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};


handler.postAtTime(runnable, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval);
handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
```

see below link for more info:-

[How to set a timer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
  public void rightAnsnextQ (View view)  {

       Toast.makeText(this, "Good job", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

          @Override
         public void run() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdQuestion.class);
                startActivity(intent);



            }

           }, 100);
  }
```

Comment: `this` does not refer to a valid context.