# Timer should run One time but with different Intervals

Tags: android, timer

I have a button on which I want to set the timer for 5 seconds for the first time and it should perform some task after completing 5 seconds. Also if user click button 2 times it should start timer for 10 seconds and after 10 seconds it should perform specific task. and if user click 3rd time it should stop all running timers. so I have do not know How to implement timer for one time 
what I have search is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android). But in this link it is continuously repeating after specific period of time, whereas I want to run once.

Now what I want

- To start timer with first click (of 5 seconds)and if meanwhile user click 2nd time it should set timer with with new time period and if user click third time it cancels out all timers.
- I do not want to use Thread timer using sleep method.
- I want same behavior as there is in camera app in android 5.0 v.

So please tell me how to do this any code and source code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the link you provided you will find the answer if you try little harder.

**For a repeating task:**

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, after, interval);
```

**For a single run of a task:**

```
new Timer().schedule(task, after);
```

So what you need to do is to maintain temporary variable to keep track of number of clicks and you can use second method like

For a repeating task:

new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, after, interval);

For a single run of a task:

```
new Timer().schedule(task, after * numberOfTimeBtnClked);
```

You have to pass the `TimerTask` method instead of task in that method.

**For updating your textview use below code and forget about whatever I have written above **

```
public void startTimer() {
       //set a new Timer
       timer = new Timer();

       //initialize the TimerTask's job
       initializeTimerTask();

       //run in an interval of 1000ms 
       timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000); //
}

public void initializeTimerTask() {

        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            timerSince++; //global integer variable with default value 0
                            if(timerSince == 5 * numberOfBtnClick){
                                //call your method
                                timer.cancel;
                                timerSince = 0;
                            }else{
                                //textView.setText(((5 * numberOfBtnClick)-timerSince)+" second left");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
        }
}
```

On event start button click call:

```
startTimer();
```

Comment: I will try it , But can you tell me , will it run on Ui Thread

Comment: No it will run on different thread. TimerTask will run on different thread. If you wan't it to run on your main thread then use `runOnUiThread `.

Comment: you are right. Now I want to show the time by time seconds on screen , I mean A count down counting numbers to show how many second are left., so how Can I do this?

Comment: I Know the Toast but I do not want to use it . Is there anyother way

Comment: Use a `TextView` and setText inside the timer

Comment: I mean 10,9,8,7,,,,,1 in this way

Comment: use a timer that will run on every second and set your TextView.
And in that same timer  you can check when it is 5 second or 10 second launch your method.

Comment: I didnt get your point but thanks anyways. It would be more appropriate if you share me a link of same thing i want . But thanks BTW

Comment: I will try to do that or some code snippet once I get some time today.

Comment: did you get some time today Kunu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74696/discussion-between-kunu-and-ghost-talker).

Comment: I slightly changed your code , As you didnt got my idea , actually I want unable to make you fully understand. My bad , But thanks

Comment: timer.schedule(timerTask,timeDelay, 1000);
making changes here , I am putting 5 or 10 in timedelay , so its  5*1000 would run for 5 sec and after completion I am taking my action and then also making my timer stop , thats it