# Android Quiz game

Tags: android

I have created simple android game. If player fails to answer all 10 question in 3 mins. An alertDialog for totalGuesses will popup and the game will terminated. My problem is how to add the timer, any modification to this code will be appreciated :)
Here is all the code in:

NewgameActivity.class

```
public class NewgameActivity extends Activity{
private static final String TAG = "NewgameActivity Activity";
private List<String> fileNameList; //game file name
private List<String> quizAnswerList; //answer
private Map<String, Boolean> gamesMap; //which game enable
private String correctAnswer; //correct answer
private int totalGuesses; //no of guesses made
private int correctAnswers; //no of correct guesses
private Random random; //random no generator
private Handler handler; //used to delay loading next image
private Animation shakeAnimation; //for incorrect guesses
private int guessRows;

private TextView answerTextView; //display correct and incorrect
private TextView questionNumberTextView; 
private ImageView imageImageView; //display image 
private TableLayout buttonTableLayout; //table for answer button

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newgame);



    fileNameList = new ArrayList<String>(); //list of image
    quizAnswerList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    gamesMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    guessRows=2;
    random = new Random(); //random number generator
    handler = new Handler();

    //load the shake animation for incorrect answer
    shakeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,     R.anim.incorrect_shake);
    shakeAnimation.setRepeatCount(3);//animation repeat 3x

    //array of games from string.xml
    String[] gameNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gameList);

    //by default, answer are chosen from all games
    for (String game : gameNames)
        gamesMap.put(game, true);

    //get references to GUI components
    questionNumberTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionNumberTextView);
    imageImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageImageView);
    buttonTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonTableLayout);
    answerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);

    //set questionNumberTextView's text
    questionNumberTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.question) + " 1 " + 
    getResources().getString(R.string.of) + " 10");


    resetQuiz(); //start a new Game


}

//set up and start the next game

private void resetQuiz(){


    //use the Assetmanager to get the image game
    //file name for the only enable game
    AssetManager assets = getAssets(); 
    fileNameList.clear();//empty the list
    try
    {
        Set<String> games = gamesMap.keySet(); //get set of games

        //loop through each game
        for (String game : games)
        {
            if (gamesMap.get(game))
            {
                String[] paths = assets.list(game);

                for (String path : paths)
                    fileNameList.add(path.replace(".png", ""));
            }
        }
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading image file names", e);

    }

    correctAnswers = 0; //reset the correct answer made
    totalGuesses = 0; //reset total
    quizAnswerList.clear();

    //add 10 random file name to quizAnswerList
    int imageCounter = 1;
    int numberOfImages = fileNameList.size();

    while (imageCounter <= 10)
    {
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(numberOfImages);

        String fileName = fileNameList.get(randomIndex);

        if (!quizAnswerList.contains(fileName))
        {
            quizAnswerList.add(fileName);
            ++imageCounter;
        }
    }

    loadNextImage();


}

//after guesses a correct answer
private void loadNextImage() {
    //get file name of the next flag and remove from the list
    String nextImageName = quizAnswerList.remove(0);
    correctAnswer = nextImageName; //update the correct answer

    answerTextView.setText(""); //clear answerTextView

    //display the number of current question in the game
    questionNumberTextView.setText(
            getResources().getString(R.string.question) + " " + (correctAnswers + 1) + " " +
    getResources().getString(R.string.of) + " 10");

    //extract the region from the next image's name
    String game = nextImageName.substring(0, nextImageName.indexOf('-'));

    //use AssetManager to load next image from assets folder
    AssetManager assets = getAssets();
    InputStream stream; //utk bace image

    try
    {
        //get an InputStream to asset representing the next image
        stream = assets.open(game + "/" + nextImageName + ".png");

        //load the asset as a Drawable and display on the imageImageView
        Drawable image = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, nextImageName);
        imageImageView.setImageDrawable(image);

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error Loading " + nextImageName, e);
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < buttonTableLayout.getChildCount(); ++row)
        ((TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row)).removeAllViews();

    Collections.shuffle(fileNameList); 
    int correct = fileNameList.indexOf(correctAnswer);
    fileNameList.add(fileNameList.remove(correct));

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     for (int row = 0; row < guessRows; row++) 
      {
         TableRow currentTableRow = getTableRow(row);
         for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) 
         {
            Button newGuessButton = 
               (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.guess_button, null);
            String fileName = fileNameList.get((row * 3) + column);
            newGuessButton.setText(getAnswerName(fileName));

            newGuessButton.setOnClickListener(guessButtonListener);
            currentTableRow.addView(newGuessButton);
         } 
      } 

     int row = random.nextInt(guessRows);
      int column = random.nextInt(3); 
      TableRow randomTableRow = getTableRow(row);
      String answerName = getAnswerName(correctAnswer);
      ((Button)randomTableRow.getChildAt(column)).setText(answerName);    
   } 
   private TableRow getTableRow(int row)
   {
      return (TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row);
   } 
   private String getAnswerName(String name)
   {
      return name.substring(name.indexOf('-') + 1).replace('_', ' ');
   }

   //called when user selects the answer
   private void submitGuess(Button guessButton)
   {
       String guess = guessButton.getText().toString();
       String answer = getAnswerName(correctAnswer);
       ++totalGuesses;//total guesses user made increment

       //if guess correct
       if (guess.equals(answer))
       {
           ++correctAnswers;

           //view jawapan dalam tulisan warna hijau
           answerTextView.setText(answer + "!");
           answerTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.correct_answer));

           disableButtons();// disable all answer buttons

           // if the user has correctly identified 10 image
           if (correctAnswers == 10)
           {
               //create a new AlerDialog Builder
               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
               builder.setTitle(R.string.taniah); 

               //set the AlertDialog's message to display game results
               // %d means integer and not double, %s tuh dia ganti string, 
               builder.setMessage(String.format("%d %s", 
                       totalGuesses, getResources().getString(R.string.guesses)
                       ));
               builder.setCancelable(false); 

               //add reset quiz
               builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_quiz,
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
               {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                   {

                       resetQuiz();
                       }
                   }
                    );
               AlertDialog resetDialog = builder.create();
               resetDialog.show();
               }

           else
               {
               handler.postDelayed(
                       new Runnable()
                       {
                        @Override
                           public void run()
                           {
                              loadNextImage();
                          }
                       }, 1000);
                 }
           }
           else
           {
               //play animation
               imageImageView.startAnimation(shakeAnimation);

               //display "Incorrect!" in red
               answerTextView.setText(R.string.incorrect_answer);
               answerTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.incorrect_answer));
               guessButton.setEnabled(false);//disable incorrect answer

           }



   }

   private void disableButtons()
   {
       for (int row = 0; row < buttonTableLayout.getChildCount(); ++row)
       {
           TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row);
           for (int i = 0; i < tableRow.getChildCount(); ++i)
               tableRow.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);

       }
   }

   //create constant for each menu id
   private final int CHOICES_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;
   private final int GAMES_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

menu.add(Menu.NONE, CHOICES_MENU_ID, Menu.NONE, R.string.choices);
menu.add(Menu.NONE, GAMES_MENU_ID, Menu.NONE, R.string.game);

return true;

}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case CHOICES_MENU_ID:
        final String[] possiblechoices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.choicesList);

        AlertDialog.Builder choicesBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        choicesBuilder.setTitle(R.string.choices);

        choicesBuilder.setItems(R.array.choicesList,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                guessRows = Integer.parseInt(possiblechoices[item].toString()) /3;
                resetQuiz();
            }
        }
        );
         AlertDialog choicesDialog = choicesBuilder.create();
         choicesDialog.show();
         return true;

    case GAMES_MENU_ID:
        //get array of game
        final String[] gameNames = gamesMap.keySet().toArray(new String[gamesMap.size()]);

        //boolean array representing whether image game enabled
        boolean[] gamesEnabled = new boolean[gamesMap.size()];
        for (int i= 0 ; i < gamesEnabled.length; ++i)
            gamesEnabled[i] = gamesMap.get(gameNames[i]);

        AlertDialog.Builder gamesBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        gamesBuilder.setTitle(R.string.game);

        String[] displayNames = new String[gameNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < gameNames.length; ++i)
            displayNames[i] = gameNames[i].replace('_', ' ');

         gamesBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems( 
                   displayNames, gamesEnabled,
                   new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() 
                   {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                         boolean isChecked) 
                      {
                       gamesMap.put(
                            gameNames[which].toString(), isChecked);
                      }
                   } 
                ); 
         gamesBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_quiz,
                   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                   {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
                      {
                         resetQuiz(); 
                      } 
                   } 
                ); 
                AlertDialog regionsDialog = gamesBuilder.create();
                regionsDialog.show();
                return true;
          } 
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       } 

private OnClickListener guessButtonListener = new OnClickListener() 
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         submitGuess((Button) v); 
      }
   }; 
}
```

Comment: Is your code working or are you having a problem with it? If you're having a problem, please edit your question to elaborate on it.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing in the code above?

Comment: My code is working, my problem is i dont know how to add timer to my quiz game.

Comment: Sorry,We Can't Just Give You CODE!!!You Tell Us The Problem We'll Solve It.

Comment: Sorry, my problem is i want to add timer to my game. My game has 10 question and player must answer the question in 3 minutes, so may i know where should i put the countdown 3 mins timer in my code.

Comment: i have posted simple timer code if it helps you but i am still not sure what exactly is your problem

Comment: sorry, i m beginner i don't know how to implement the code to make its function with timer. Thanks for reply and i will try :(

Answer (score 0):

simple timer example

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
      // do work here
  }
}, 0, 10000);
```

also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android) and [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)