# AndroidStudio - How to add a loop and delay (in minutes)

Tags: java, android, loops, android-studio, delay

I have the following void:

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    PostDataTask postDataTask = new PostDataTask();

    postDataTask.execute(URL,textView3.getText().toString(),textView5.getText().toString(),textView12.getText().toString(),textView13.getText().toString(),textView14.getText().toString(),textView7.getText().toString(),textView15.getText().toString());

}
```

And I want to loop the "postDataTask.execute(...)" so it will be executed every 30 minutes for 24 hours (so executing 48 times in total). Can someone help me with this?

*EDIT

So I used the 1st suggestion given, but it only runs 1 time 60 seconds. Is it because it have the class in onCreate? :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final PostDataTask postDataTask = new PostDataTask();
    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    final Runnable exec = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            postDataTask.execute(URL, textView3.getText().toString(), textView5.getText().toString(), textView12.getText().toString(), textView13.getText().toString(), textView14.getText().toString(), textView7.getText().toString(), textView15.getText().toString());

        }
    };

    final ScheduledFuture execHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(exec, 60, 60, SECONDS);
    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            execHandle.cancel(true);
        }
    }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a timer in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScheduledExecutorService` can do the thing.

**Usage Example**

Here is a class with a method that sets up a `ScheduledExecutorService` to beep every ten seconds for an hour:

```
 import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

   public void beepForAnHour() {
     final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
       public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); 
     };
     final ScheduledFuture beeperHandle =
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
     scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
       public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
     }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
   }
 }}
```

[Code from `ScheduledExecutorService` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Comment: I think this will work. Can I use it like I did below *EDIT ?

Comment: Yeah, that should do the thing. Although you can change from `MINUTES` to `SECONDS` to test it.

Comment: It works well, but afterwards I came to the conclusion it wasn't really suited for the project. Nonetheless thanks for your response!

Comment: I checked code with fragment in `OnCreate` method and `Log.e` to check execution, it works.