# How to re-create Timer class object after canceling it?

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm making an Android app that turns on/off the flash light after a specified interval, by the user. It works well except when the Timer object is re-created after calling the .cancel() method for the second time, it crashes the app every time.
Here's the initialization part:

```
Timer timer; //variable of Timer class
TimerTask timerTask; //variable of TimerTask class
```

And here's the method that is called when the button responsible to turn blinking on/off is pressed:

```
blink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            delay = Integer.valueOf(startDelay.getText().toString());
            gap = Integer.valueOf(blinkDelay.getText().toString());

            if(!isBlinking) { //isBlinking is a boolean to know whether to stop or re-start timer
                timer = new Timer(); //I'm creating an object of Timer class every time.
                isBlinking = true;
                timer.schedule(timerTask, delay, gap);

            }
            else{
                isBlinking = false;
                stoptimertask(); //this will cancel the 'timer' and make it null.
            }
        }
    });
```

The 'stoptimertask()' method from above code has:

```
public void stoptimertask() {
    //stop the timer, if it's not already null

    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }

}
```

I'm setting the 'timertask' variable of TimerTask class from the method shown below. It is called in the onCreate() method of the main activity:

```
public void initializeTimerTask() {

    timerTask = new TimerTask() { //This is passed as the first argument to the timer.schedule() method
        public void run() {//Basically turns on/off flash. Works well.
            if(!state) {
                turnOnFlash();
                state = true;

            }
            else {
                turnOffFlash();
                state = false;
            }

        }
    };
```

My question is that why does the app crash when I press the blink button the third time?

- When it is pressed for the first time, isBlinking is false, so the if block executes creating a new object of the Timer class and starting the timer.
- When it is pressed for the second time, stoptimertask() is called which cancels the timer and sets timer variable to null.
- When it is pressed again for the third time with different values for delay and gap, a new object of Timer class should be created, but the application crashes unexpectedly with a "Unfortunately the app has stopped" error. 
  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to purge as well.

```
timer.cancel();
timer.purge();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to `purge` after `cancel`.

Your code must be for `stoptimertask()` method.

```
public void stoptimertask() {
    //stop the timer, if it's not already null
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
    }
}
```

Related Link:

1. [Android timer? How-to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how?rq=1)
2. [How to set a timer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android/10101190#10101190)

**UPDATE:**

Since Timer creates a new thread, **it may be considered heavy**,

if all you need is to get is a call back while the activity is running a **Handler** can be used in conjunction with this link
[How to set a timer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android/3975337#3975337)

Comment: Just tried adding `timer.purge()` but the app still crashed like before.

Comment: @e_cobra on that case, you can use scheduleAtFixedRate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android/10101190#10101190