# Unique Timer for saving(SharedPreferences) elapsed time in activity

Tags: android

as always Thanks for reading and thinking on this question.

I want to save elapsed time in some activities and using them later, i thought SharedPreferences would be a good choice for saving, but i found Using Chronometer not efficient. I'll appreciate any help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your variable:

long lastTimeRecorded;

Then in onCreate get a start time:

```
lastTimeRecorded = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then when you update the time call this function from the activity:

```
public void updateTimer(){

long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastRecordedTime;
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.edit().putLong("elapsedTime", elapsedTime);
}
```

If you want it to repeat at certain intervals:

```
private final int interval = 1000; // in millis
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        updateTimer();
    }
};
...
handler.postAtTime(runnable, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval);
handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
```

From samuel, here
[How to set a timer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android)

Comment: Thank you so much. That was just right for what i needed. :)

Comment: Happy to help. I had to build a timer not that long ago, so it was good to review.