# Get Time from firebase database and start timer from now in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am storing the time in firebase realtime database from the time picker. Here is my code:

```
 time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(AddMatch.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                        time.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                    }
                }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
                mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                mTimePicker.show();

            }
        });
```

**Now, I want to get this time from database and start the timer from now to the time which we get from database**. How we can do this in android studio?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android?

Comment: Already checked this but its not working. Thanks

Comment: If you tried to get something working, it's custom on stack overflow to show what you tried - instead of asking a more open-ended "how can I do this?" question.